# Grails g:render template from plugin - not found

Tags: templates, grails, plugins, render

I need to render a template from a plugin to a .gsp page. I wrote : `<g:render plugin="melanin 2.0.0" template="/m-melanin-fingerprint/m-melanin-fingerprint-sidebar"/>`

But then I get this error :

> Error 500: Error processing GroovyPageView: Template not found for
>   name [/m-melanin-fingerprint/m-melanin-fingerprint-sidebar] and path
>   [/m-melanin-fingerprint/_m-melanin-fingerprint-sidebar.gsp] Servlet:
>   grails URI: /RBCS/grails/VIBAction/index.dispatch Exception Message:
>   Template not found for name
>   [/m-melanin-fingerprint/m-melanin-fingerprint-sidebar] and path
>   [/m-melanin-fingerprint/_m-melanin-fingerprint-sidebar.gsp] Caused by:
>   Error processing GroovyPageView: Template not found for name
>   [/m-melanin-fingerprint/m-melanin-fingerprint-sidebar] and path
>   [/m-melanin-fingerprint/_m-melanin-fingerprint-sidebar.gsp] Class:
>   actionPlan.gsp At Line: [40] Code Snippet: 39:  40:  41:

This is my project:

[image]

Please help me fix it. Sorry my English is not good. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try removing the version from your plugin-ref:

```
<g:render plugin="melanin" template="/m-melanin-fingerprint/m-melanin-fingerprint-sidebar"/>
```